# Unable to install CMake in Ubuntu 16.04 Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, cmake

I proceeded as below :

```
cd cmake-3.13.4

sudo ./bootstrap

sudo make

sudo make install
```

I received the error :

```
make: 'cmake' is up to date.
loading initial cache file /home/agnivo/Desktop/cmake/cmake-3.18.5/Bootstrap.cmk/InitialCacheFlags.cmake
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at Utilities/cmcurl/CMakeLists.txt:485 (message):
  Could not find OpenSSL.  Install an OpenSSL development package or
  configure CMake with -DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL=OFF to build without OpenSSL.
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Umm … are the error messages not clear enough? You need to install some dependencies or reconfigure `cmake` to not depend on them 

Comment: I used the following : ./configure --DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL=OFF
but i still get error message